# Regex function to run through each line in a file and extract whole line with specific word

Tags: python, regex

I am working on a regex code in python to search for a regex pattern each line in the file and extract required patterns Few lines of the file looks like this

```
The Liz Copeland
```

Monday April 1, 2018
No. stay song () listened comment

I want to extract title and header from the file
-Every title has Liz Copeland in the line and line ends with 5 tabs and output should show as below

```
The Liz Copeland
```

-Every header has a tab followed by 5 tab separated column headers and output is as follows

> No. stay song () listened comment

I have written a function to extract the regex lines

```py
title = re.compile(r'([^.?!]*[.?\s!]Liz Copeland [^.?!]*[.?\s!])\t')

header = re.compile(r'\t\w+.\t.+')

with open(file) as f:
    for line in f:
        m_show = re.match(title, line)
        m_header = re.match(header, line)
```

The above code, is not pulling up all the lines with matching patterns and it is giving me unwanted results

Please help me with the code. Thank you in advance

Comment: You can try something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/7LliRS/2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using the following regex:

```
.*?Liz Copeland.+?\(\d{1,2}[ap]m-\d{1,2}[ap]m\)\s+$
```

Demo:

https://regex101.com/r/BjTrgU/1/

It matches the whole line where Liz Copeland is present with the ending spaces

Comment: anonymous13: could you mark answers as correct and vote up? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To get the title you could match the name `Liz Copeland` between word boundaries `\b` and match 5 tabs at the end of the string:

```
.*?\bLiz Copeland\b.*\t{5}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ofl57N/1)

To match the header you could use:

```
\tNo\.\tArtist\tSong\tAlbum \(Label\)\tComment\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6poZbH/3)

Not that the last line `buy 44661   Laurent Garnier The Man with the Red Face` misses the content between parenthesis like the previous ones in the example data.

Comment: Regex works for title perfectly. Regex for header should only match " No. Artist Song Album (Label) Comment", it matches other lines too

Comment: @anonymous13 The you could match it like this https://regex101.com/r/6poZbH/2 I have updated the answer.

Comment: I tried \t\w+.\t\w+\t\w+\t\w+\s\(\w+\)\t\w+$ for header line and it works. Thank you